# Strange jump in cellForRowAtIndexPath to another return statement

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, if-statement, exc-bad-access

I have this in my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if (condition) {
    // make a custom cell
    return cell;  // line number 240
}
else {
    // make another kind of cell
    return cell;  // line number 256
}
```

I got a EXC_BAD_ACCESS, so I fired up the debugger and set a breakpoint, stepping through the code line by line.

When I stepped forward "step over" from line number 256 **it went directly to line 240**, i.e. into another branch of the `if` statement. How is that possible???

Thanks a lot for your help,
Sascha

Comment: What version of XCode and what compiler are you using?

Comment: XCode 4.0.2, compiler LLVM GCC 4.2.

Comment: Try whether the same happens with GCC 4.2. I've had some bad experiences with LLVM, at least in release mode.

Comment: Same effect. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the solution. The view controller with the table view is also the **delegate** of a background web loading thread. Apparently the debugger can only step through one thread at a time. The delegate routine did indeed call a `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:` without checking the above `condition`.

Still, I find the behavior of the debugger a bit puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

`(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` will get called x times, where x = number of rows.

So I think your problem is that your `(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` doesn't return a correct value, and very likely a value that's greater than where you're pulling data from.

i.e. If you have a array of size 3, but trying to make the 4th row cell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `numberOfRowsInSection:` is correct. Also, the debugger jumps to the other line **on the next step forward**, not the next time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

This method calls itself the same number of times as the number of rows returned in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method and **each time a cell is nil**. Most likely, the control went to the next row to allocate the `UITableViewCell` for it, and at that time, I am guessing that the `if` condition got satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked, the condition remains unsatisfied. Also, the function does not seem to get called again. Line number 240 does not have a breakpoint. The pointer of the **debugger** jumps to 240 on the next step. This is what really puzzles me.

Comment: The only way control can go up there is if you had used `Loops` (for, while, etc..) or `Recursion` (cellForRowAtIndexPath). You should check control flow and post NSLogs :) That can  make us understand and help you with the Logical issues.

Comment: Thank you, I know. But what does the debugger's "step over" function do? It should step to the **next** line to execute. Even in the case of loops it is inconceivable that it **remains in the same function** and steps into a **different branch** of an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

**Step Over is the same as Step Into, except that when it reaches a call for another procedure, it will not step into the procedure. The procedure will run, and you will be brought to the next statement in the current procedure.**

so step over get the next statement and your cellForRowAtIndexPath call numberOfRow times. so in some iteration your if condition becomes true and goes to your line no 240

Comment: That does not make sense. If the function is indeed called again, "step over" should go to the beginning of the function (i.e. the `if` statement), not line 240.